# Anyone know What type of tree is this

Tags: trees

Small tree in northern Indiana has small pea-sized metallic blue/purple berries. Were small white flowers before the berries came out.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Try "Silky dogwood" or "Cornus amomum". Many pictures of those metallic blue berries available on line, and that blue is certainly an amazing shade. A picture and quote from   http://www.yellowfarmhousegarden.com/?m=201508   :

[image: Silky dogwood at the yellow farmhouse garden]

Quote: "I’ve never been tempted to try to eat these berries, even as a young child. Something about that blue just didn’t look right to me."

.....Me, I wish I could see that plant in person, but I guess I am out of its range, as it seems to prefer the Eastern half of the US (minus the far-Southern region).